# Share iPhone developer account for multiple devices

Tags: developer-program

I have a question, is it possible to share a developer account between a couple of devices? The reason is, I want to build a certain open source software myself, and upload to mine, and mine friends devices. We do not want to sell any applications etc in store, just use open source software, modified to our needs to communicate with each other. Is it possible? Or maybe there is a some free alternative besides jailbreak?

Answer (score 2):

> You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php)

-> Yes. Yes it is possible.